# Sass/CSS image-constraints not being enforced?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am new to front-end design and I am trying put together a website for fun. I want to put some images on a page and make them small(er). It was working, then I added the nests for `--p1` &2,3 and then it stopped being enforced. I don't see a stray squigle or semicolon and I've cut and pasted every name over each other so many times they are definitely spelled the same. I used my rubber duck and I can't for the life of me understand why its not working. I have cleared the browser cache so many times I lost count. No other properties seem to have been affected, it is only these. Browser I'm testing in is Chrome v83.0. (I have never posted a front-end question on SO before, if you need a larger/more code snippet please tell me!)

Sass file is included in the imports.

```
<!--html snippet-->
<div class="col-1-of-2">
            <div class="composition">
              <img src="images/DSC_0032.JPG" alt="" class="composition__photo composition__photo--p1">
              <img src="images/DSC_0034.JPG" alt="" class="composition__photo composition__photo--p2">
              <img src="images/DSC_0036.JPG" alt="" class="composition__photo composition__photo--p3">
            </div>
          </div>
```

```
//sass snippet//
.composition {
    position: relative;

    &___photo{
        max-width: 10%; /* have also tried with just `width` */
        box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 3rem rgba($col-btn-shade, .4);
        border-radius: 20px;
        position: absolute;

        &--p1{
            left: 0;
            top: -2rem;
        }

        &--p2{
            left: 0;
            top: -1rem;  
        }

        &--p3{
            left: 0;
            top: -5rem;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/*css snippet*/
.composition {
  position: relative; }
  .composition___photo {
    max-width: 10%;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 3rem rgba(85, 30, 148, 0.4);
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute; }
    .composition___photo--p1 {
      left: 0;
      top: -2rem; }
    .composition___photo--p2 {
      left: 0;
      top: -1rem; }
    .composition___photo--p3 {
      left: 0;
      top: -5rem; }
```

Comment: In your HTML, the `composition__photo` and similar class names use two (2) underscores; however, in your SCSS/CSS, `.composition___photo` and similar selectors use three (3) underscores.

Comment: i'm going to scream lol. thank you so much for being a second pair of eyes.

Comment: lol well it was and also wasn't that. for whatever reason it stopped compiling my changes (i imagine because it hit an error) and restarting that worked.